# Workbox invisibly caching JS and CSS assets

Tags: google-chrome, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I'm using Workbox with Webpack to cache several assets on my site at runtime and deliver them with a Service Worker. I'm able to successfully view images from an external CDN in the Cache Storage and confirm they are delivered via SW.

However, when it comes to locally hosted (same origin) assets like JS and CSS files, their named cache appears empty. Upon loading the page, these assets are delivered `(from ServiceWorker)` and there is no additional network request from the SW. Refreshing Cache Storage or the cache itself does not make a difference.

Here's the Webpack config:

```
new GenerateSW({
    include: [],
    runtimeCaching: [{
        urlPattern: /.*javascript.*/,
        handler: 'cacheFirst',
        options: {
            cacheName: 'js',
            cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [0, 200],
            },
        },
    }],
}),
```

- How is it that these assets are being delivered by SW if they do not appear in the cache?
- Is there some reason they're invisible within the cache?

Answer (score 0):

GenerateSW knows about the assets bundled by webpack, and generates service worker code for caching those files. You should find them in the cache named workbox-**precache**-http://localhost:port/.

See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/codelabs/webpack

If you add a breakpoint in your service worker js file and inspect `self.__precacheManifest` (with a console.log), you see as well which ressources are precached for you.

Comment: Yeah I found the cache, it just appears empty. However, the SW loads the items from its cache without a network call. I was curious how this was possible.